# django css doesn't load from the index url and not any other url

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

why css loads from the index url and not any other url?

urls:

```
    urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("product/<slug>", views.product, name="product"),] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
#+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

views.py:

```
def index(request):
return render(request, "product.html")

def product(request, slug):
    product = Product.objects.get(slug='iphone-11')
    print(product.image1.url)
    context = {'product': product}
    return render(request, "product.html", context)
```

product.html:

> {%load static%}
>
> ```
> <meta charset="UTF-8">
> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
> <title>Nakahaty</title>
> <meta name="keywords" content="HTML5 Template">
> <meta name="description" content="Molla - Bootstrap eCommerce Template">
> <meta name="author" content="p-themes">
> <!-- Favicon -->
> <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="static/assets/images/icons/apple-touch-icon.png">
> <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="static/assets/images/icons/favicon-32x32.png">
> <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="static/assets/images/icons/favicon-16x16.png">
> <link rel="manifest" href="static/assets/images/icons/site.html">
> <link rel="mask-icon" href="static/assets/images/icons/safari-pinned-tab.svg"
> ```
>
> color="#666666">

Edit: when I load the same HTML file from the index URL it works otherwise it doesn`t load css files

ps:without using the form

```
{% static ..%}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of Django if you use Django:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="{% static 'assets/images/icons/apple-touch-icon.png' %}">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="{% static 'assets/images/icons/favicon-32x32.png' %}">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="{% static 'assets/images/icons/favicon-16x16.png' %}">
<link rel="manifest" href="{% static 'assets/images/icons/site.html' %}">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="{% static 'assets/images/icons/safari-pinned-tab.svg' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'your css folder/ your css file name' %}
```

Have a read about [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the static url like this.

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="manifest" href=" {% static 'static/assets/images/icons/site.html' %}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Your path to a static file is incorrect. It should look like:

````
{% load static %}
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="{% static 'assets/images/icons/apple-touch-icon.png' %}">```
````